# Make an extruded circle along a path into a solid object

Tags: mesh, transforms, 3d-printing

I'm trying my hand at 3d printing with blender. Right now I want to create an object that has a 3d curve - so it's essentially a horizontally placed cylinder curved around the Y axis on the whole object, and then curved along the Z axis for the last third of the object. I've found I can model exactly what I want by creating a curved path, then extruding a circle along the path.

However, I haven't found a way to 'apply' this transform so that my 2 objects become one editable object where I can close off the faces and select and edit nodes. Can anyone tell me of a way to do this? I also tried having a straight cylinder object and applying the curve modifier, but found that only worked along one axis, and attempting to use 2 curve modifiers on the same object gave funny results.

Comment: can you add an image that illustrates the shape you want to get?

Comment: Did you try selecting your tube and using Alt+C (Mesh From Curve/Meta/Surf/Text)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **join two meshes** by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, however **make sure they are both a mesh** before attempting this. As Reactive said, you can convert a curve into a mesh using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> *> Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text*. If it is using a modifier, simply press the *Apply* button before joining the meshes.